# How do I make links to blog posts available to DjangoCMS when using djangocms-blog?

Tags: django, django-cms

I use DjangoCMS (3.2.3) on Django 1.8.12 along with djangocms-blog (0.7). I would like to link blog-posts

- in other posts
- on other DjangoCMS pages

The app-hooked blog page is available with CMS' Link plugin. However, I do not see how I could link individual posts.

The only and in my eyes dirty workaround I have found is using the app-hooks URL and hard-coding the post's slug directly behind it. It only works if the post URLs are in "slug-only" mode, i.e. w/o categories etc.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no generic way to link objects handled by apphooks in the same way as django CMS pages. Providing a solution in a specific application is not trivial, as you basically needs a custom widget to do this

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [`djangocms-styledlink`](https://github.com/mkoistinen/djangocms-styledlink). Despite the styling capability this link package allows to configure links to other apps, too. For `djangocms-blog` I added following lines to the setup:

```
DJANGOCMS_STYLEDLINK_MODELS = [
    {
        'type': _('CMS Pages'),
        'class_path': 'cms.models.Page',
        'manager_method': 'public',
        'filter': { 'publisher_is_draft': False },
    },
    {
        'type': _('Blog pages'),
        'class_path': 'djangocms_blog.models.Post',
        'filter': { 'publish': True },
    }
]
```

It seems that currently `djangocms-styledlink` only works with python 2.